# jQuery selecting multiple classes but changing .css for one of them on current instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to do the following:

I need to calculate a padding for element based on the width of the element itself and the element below it, I am having trouble with applying the padding to the current instance of .class1 element, for some reason it does not get applied, my code is:

```
function myFunction() {
    $('.class1, .class2').each(function (){
      var Width1 = $(this).filter('.class1').width();
      var Width2 = $(this).filter('.class2').width();
      var paddingSize = "+=" + (Width1 - Width2) / 2;
      $(this).filter('.class1').css( "padding-left", paddingSize );
  });
}
```

So I guess I am failing with the filter function and it is not supposed to be used in this case? If I simply apply the change to $(this), the padding will be applied on .class2 as well and this is not intended.

edit: fixed typo

Comment: What happens if you have multiple `.class1` and `.class2`?

Comment: can you please provide jsfiddle please. https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Add some units to your padding css, it's just a number at the moment.`.css("padding-left", paddingSize + 'px')` and this is creating a string not an number ` var paddingSize = "+=" + (Width1 - Width2) / 2; `

Comment: Nothing happens even if I do add the 'px' at the end. i also tried changing to :      
var paddingSize = (coverWidth - textWidth) / 2;
$(this).filter('.class1').css( "padding-left", "+="+paddingSize);

but nothing happens.

Comment: My mistake on the +=, ignore that comment. I have some code below if I have understood your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
function myFunction() 
{
  $('.class1').each(function ()
  {
    var elem = $(this);
    var width1 = elem.width();      
    var width2 = elem.next('.class2').width();
    var paddingSize = (width1 - width2) / 2;

    elem.css("padding-left", "+=" + paddingSize);
  });
}
```

This will only work if your `.class1` and `.class2` are siblings of the same parent.

Answer (score 0):

- Separate the selectors to get the specific widths.
- If you have multiple `.class1` or `.class2`, you need to handle that. If that's not the case, use `id` instead.

---

```
function myFunction() {
  var Width1, Width2,
    $class1 = $('.class1');

  $class1.each(function() {  // Take care with multiple elements
    Width1 = $(this).width();
  });

  $('.class2').each(function() {  // Take care with multiple elements
    Width2 = $(this).width();
  });

  var paddingSize = "+=" + (Width1 - Width2) / 2;
  $class1.css("padding-left", paddingSize); // px Unit, but this is up to you.
}
```